# about sql get date

Tags: sql

When I use

```
DATE_PART('year', MIN(child.dob) - father.dob) AS age
```

it reports

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist

So how to solve the question?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: date_part generally expects a date, but child.dob - father.dob is probably giving you seconds as int.